# WP-PostRatings - Return 4 or 5 star post at random

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked through this support forum but was unable to find what im looking for so apologies if ive missed the answer.

I am developing a query_posts arguments list to return a random custom post type with a rating of 4 or above.

My current code looks like:

```
$query_args['post_type'] = 'recipes';
$query_args['post_status'] = 'publish';
$query_args['r_sortby'] = 'highest_rated';
$query_args['r_orderby'] = 'rand';
$query_args['posts_per_page'] = '1';
query_posts($query_args);
```

This is returning the highest rated recipe. How can I amend to only return a random 4/5 star recipe?

Thanks very much.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working using the following for anyone who is interested:

```
    $query_args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'ratings_average',
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'value' => array(4,5) // 4 or 5 star recipes
        )
    );
    $query_args['post_type'] = 'recipes';
    $query_args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $query_args['orderby'] = 'rand';
    $query_args['posts_per_page'] = '1'; 
    query_posts($query_args);
```